# Parsear DateTime a un string c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Tengo la fecha que recibí de la llamada de API entrante: miércoles 6 de marzo de 2019 14:39:49 +0300 Necesito analizar esta cadena a DateTime. Para esto estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Sun, 10 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300", 
                     new string[] { "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz" },
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Pero te me da este error

> String 'Sun, 10 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300' was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.

Comment: Estás seguro? Yo acabo de probar tu código y funciona correctamente...Aqui puedes verlo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4QM8vn . O lo que quieres parsear es `miércoles 6 de marzo de 2019 14:39:49 +0300`?

Comment: tu codigo funciona (retorna 10-03-2019 11:39:49)

Comment: @Pikoh debe querer pasar miércoles 6 de marzo de 2019 14:39:49 +0300 a datetime

Comment: tbn es muy raro recibir las fechas de un API con ese formato, por lo regular siempre se utilizan [formatos de fecha internacional](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date.html.es)

Comment: Documentación oficial: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes varias cosas mal. Por un lado,la cadena de parseo debe ser `"dddd d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"`.

> dddd - día de la semana en formato largo
>
> d- día del mes
>
> 'de' - la cadena `de` exactamente
>
> MMMM - Mes en formato largo
>
> yyyy - año con 4 dígitos
>
> HH:mm:ss - hora en formato 24 h
>
> zzzz - zona horaria

Por otro, en lugar de `InvariantCulture` debes usar `CurrentCulture` o una cultura en español (por ejemplo, `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-es")`) para que funcione:

```
var fecha=DateTime.ParseExact("miércoles 6 de marzo de 2019 14:39:49 +0300",
                 new string[] { "dddd d 'de' MMMM 'de' yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz" },
                 CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Answer (score 3):

Esa fecha que te llega esta en inglés, y si por defecto donde corres el código la culturización está en español te puede dar problemas, lo mejor es siempre tratar de utilizar una cultura en específico en tu caso sería inglés.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Sun, 10 Mar 2019 14:39:49 +0300", 
    new string[] { "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz" },
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```